# Android - Manifest placeholders for different build types

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I am very hyped about the new possibility of manifest placeholders in Gradle + Android Build. I've found in the gradle documentation that I can specify my own placeholders like this:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
    }
    pro {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ activityLabel:"proName" ]
    }
}
```

But I would like to have one placeholder dependent on build type and not on product flavors. When I insert that placeholder specification into build type settings it takes no effect. Do you know how to achieve this? Because it seems to me stupid have three build types and three flavors associated with it. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about your case but maybe this link will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887837/how-to-specify-spring-propertyplaceholderconfig-values-in-gradle-build

Comment: Since I didn't get this to work directly and didn't have time to test a lot of different ways I finally decided to copy my Manifest in the different build type folders and remove (almost) everything except what I wanted to change (In my case this was the Google Maps API key). I used the "tools:replace" method to make sure I kept what I wanted.
Not the best solution but a work around that worked for me...

Comment: Seems a bug, that is going to be fixed: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=72829

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting today with gradle plugin 0.13.0 is already working.

Answer (score 7):

This is my solution for different product flavours:

build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
normal {
    applicationId "mobi.cwiklinski.urc"
    buildConfigField "String", "providerAuthority", "\"mobi.cwiklinski.urc.provider\""
    resValue "string", "authorities", "mobi.cwiklinski.urc.provider"
}
adfree {
    applicationId "mobi.cwiklinski.urc.adfree"
    buildConfigField "String", "providerAuthority", "\"mobi.cwiklinski.urc.adfree.provider\""
    resValue "string", "authorities", "mobi.cwiklinski.urc.adfree.provider"
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
        android:name="mobi.cwiklinski.urc.provider.AppProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/authorities"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:syncable="true"
        android:writePermission="mobi.cwiklinski.urc.permission.USE_PROVIDER" />
```

And that's all - in different product flavours you will get different resource value.

Comment: Well, thanks for answer, but it has nothing to do with my question .. i was asking if I could somehow utilize this in build types and not in flavors

Comment: You can connect this two things - you will get four APKs and choose the two you want to get...

Comment: I didn't know resValue, it is really helpful and can be used instead of `manifestPlaceholders` which I couldn't get them work.